# Ubuntu says Python is on its latest version when its not. How do I update it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am clueless here. I need to upgrade to python 3.8.0. So, I run this:

```
 sudo apt-get install python3 3.8.0
```

But I get the following message:

[image]

As you can see. It writes "python3 is already the newest version". It is not.

Also, I get the "held broken packages" error after that. I am not sure if they are related.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is much better placed on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/),

Comment: As upgrading python from 2.7 to python 3.6 is not recommended https://superuser.com/questions/241865/updating-python-on-ubuntu-system

Comment: it is natural for many Linux distributions. They create repo with programs tested by repo authors and you can't find the newest version. Maybe in next  edition of Ubuntu you will find Python 3.8.0.  You may have to use unofficial repo created by [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Probably to have access to the newest version all time (without restriction) you would have to use distribution like Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

you might have the newest version of tthat particular's repository.

try here:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.8
sudo apt install python3.8-distutils
python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```